# Traffic Light style form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am creating a easy to use form web app that uses button presses to generate answers.

I would like the boxes to either show a colour or display a number and if possible both, then once press it then only shows the number or dims the other boxes so you can clearly see that you have pressed box 3 for example. I would like this to eventually to record what button is pressed and then be added to a form.

Any idea how I can create such buttons?

Comment: post the code you tried?

Comment: Do not use the visual appearance (number, color) to record what button was clicked!

Comment: So far I havent started writing any code, I was wondering if firstly this was possible and if so how difficult (I know little code, but I am reading my books to get used to it) and next if anyone could point me in a good direction, advice something to read.

Comment: This is a site for developers.  If you wish to try writing some code, we will help you with that.  However, we won't just give you the code.

Comment: Ok thats fine, but this is something I can do with Javascript?

Comment: @SPalmer Yes.  Javascript, CSS, HTML... these are the things you need to focus on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could achive this by using radiobutton´s labels,
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

you hide the actual radiobuttons and style the labels like a traffic light or whatever,
so when you click the label it will automatically check the radiobutton.

with a bit of javascript/css and helperclasses you can easyily achive your desired effect (eg. blending out the other labels etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Give all the buttons a class and then something like:

```
$('.btnClass').click(function() {
  $('.btnClass').css('opacity', 0.5);
  $(this).css ('opacity', 1);
  });
```

That will dim the non-selected buttons.